# how to run a bash that must be run with a specific user with another user without password

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, privileges, nologin

I have 2 users. `test1` that i created it with `/sbin/nologin` and has no password. `test2` that has `sudo` privilege and has passworsd.

I have this script: `/data/tempWork/fazitst` that must be run under `test2`. now i want to run this script with `test1` but i want it to be run under `test2`.

I tried this as `test1`:
`/bin/su -c "/data/tempWork/fazitst " - test2`

but it didn't work. i was running this command from an application since i can't use `ssh` i can't debug this properly. there is no log. I tried this command with root and it worked.

but i guess that it requires password. so how i can run my script with `test1` under `test2` with no password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what `sudo` was designed for.

First, someone with root access will need to make a configuration line like this to `/etc/sudoers` (or `/etc/sudoers.d/*`, if supported by your OS version):

```
test1 ALL=(test2) NOPASSWD: /data/tempWork/fazitst
```

This will authorize user `test1` (on `ALL` hosts using a copy of that `sudoers` file) to execute as user `test2`, without a password request, the command `/data/tempWork/fazitst` with any command-line parameters (or none at all).

Then, user `test1` can execute it with:

```
sudo -u test2 /data/tempWork/fazitst
```

If the `$HOME` environment variable needs to point to the home directory of user `test2` while executing the command, you may or may not need to add the `-H` option to the `sudo` command, depending on the default configuration of `sudo` in your OS version. In that case, the command for user `test1` to run would be:

```
sudo -Hu test2 /data/tempWork/fazitst
```

If it is important that the environment is set exactly the same as when running `su - test2`, then the `-i` option of `sudo` is needed:

```
sudo -iu test2 /data/tempWork/fazitst
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. i had to use full path `/usr/bin/sudo` in my application.